# How to get CPU cores' energy consumption in Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, cpu

I am doing experiments on an dynamic voltage and frequency scaling(DVFS) algorithm, and need to get CPU core's energy consumption in Linux kernel.

I am thinking of using **powercap** [Power Capping Framework](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/power/powercap/powercap.html).

Here is the **powercap_zone_ops** structure provided in **powercap.h**:

```
struct powercap_zone_ops {
int (*get_max_energy_range_uj) (struct powercap_zone *, u64 *);
int (*get_energy_uj) (struct powercap_zone *, u64 *);
int (*reset_energy_uj) (struct powercap_zone *);
int (*get_max_power_range_uw) (struct powercap_zone *, u64 *);
int (*get_power_uw) (struct powercap_zone *, u64 *);
int (*set_enable) (struct powercap_zone *, bool mode);
int (*get_enable) (struct powercap_zone *, bool *mode);
int (*release) (struct powercap_zone *);};
```

It looks like **get_energy_uj** perfectly meets my needs. To register a power zone, I need to use **struct device** to describe my CPU, but I don't know how to do it.

It would be a very valuable help for me if someone could show me some examples.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you just trying to query an existing Linux kernel's report of power usage? If so, you don't need any kernel code to do it, the data is exposed to userspace. Or are you trying to write kernel code to monitor power consumption of a new CPU interface? It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need to get each period's consumption at a high frequency, read it from user-level would cause I/O overhead and data delay. So what I want is monitoring CPU's energy consumption in the kernel's CPUFreq driver each time I do DVFS.

Comment: I do know the powecap outputs data via sysfs to userspace, so I think it should be possible to directly get it in kernel-level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 cases - averaged power consumption of a longer period of time (that can't be used for high frequency measurements), and instantaneous power consumption (that could be used for high frequency measurements).

For the first case (averaged power consumption over a longer period of time) there wasn't any support in the CPU itself until recently (maybe the last 5 years?) and most other parts of the computer still don't support it. Fixing those problems takes a huge amount of work building databases of "max. power consumption for each piece of hardware" (in drivers, etc) and writing code to try to estimate how close the hardware is to its maximum based on the load it was given; but no OS supports this. In addition (or as an alternative); you might be able to get an "overall total power consumption" from the power supply chain - from an external UPS, or from laptop battery management (but if you only care about the power consumption of CPUs then that's useless).

For the second case; almost no hardware (and almost no CPUs) support it. You have to estimate it. For CPUs, estimating instantaneous power consumption would involve intercepting all power consumption changes, which means intercepting software/voluntary power management changes (typically the result of CPUs being idle) and hardware/involuntary power management changes (typically the result of CPUs reaching a "max. temperature" limit) plus anything that effects scheduling (how many cores are in use at any instant in time) plus things like AVX use/disuse (because CPU will consume more power and reduce its clock frequency when AVX is being used). Of course no OS supports this either.

However; it's worse than that. For instantaneous values there's a latency/sampling problem. If your software checks the instantaneous values at intervals it will get stale information that is potentially misleading (e.g. if power consumption is fluctuating between 100W at some instants and 5W at other instants then you might only see "100W samples" and might only see "5W samples" and for either case you won't be able to tell that the samples are misleading). To fix that problem you must store data as "durations" (a list of many "from start time to end time the power consumption was .." entries) and design interfaces/APIs for "durations"; so that the "durations" entries can be used to find the right value at any past instant, accurately estimate the value for a future instant (not forgetting that "now (taking into account 123 nanoseconds of latency)" is equivalent to estimating a value that is 123 nanoseconds in the future) and calculate an average over any time period. Again; no OS supports that either (not even for other things where it'd be easier).

> It looks like get_energy_uj perfectly meets my needs.

Powercap is a convenient (more portable, more accessible) abstraction on top of what the hardware (Intel) provides.

If you dig into Intel's manuals you'll find that "per CPU" or "per core" power consumption information doesn't exist (AMD CPUs provide the same information. I don't know about other manufacturers like ARM but would assume they provide less information). The closest is the "MSR_PP0_ENERGY_STATUS" MSR which (should, on newer CPUs sans errata) give a running count of joules consumed for all cores combined, with unknown (undocumented as far as I can tell) "time between updates" and no way to track historical information. Software must poll this MSR, and therefore software can only get an average (over the time between polls) and can not determine instantaneous values.

Note that the uncertainty principle should not be overlooked - any attempt to measure power consumption in software will create overhead that increases power consumption. This will be especially problematic if you want to poll an MSR at high frequency when CPU/s would have otherwise been idle (where "measuring" will cause an extreme increase the power consumption being measured).